# @XmlElementWrapper isn't working for me

Tags: xml, jaxb

this is my definition that don't retrieve the list of elements in the wrapped elements:

```java
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "channels")
@XmlElement(name = "channel")
private ArrayList<Channel>  expChannels;

public ArrayList<Channel> getChannels() {
   return this.expChannels;
}

public void setChannels(ArrayList<Channel> listOfChannels) {
   this.expChannels = listOfChannels;
}
```

And this is the declaration of Channel model object:

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class Channel {

    //Channel() {}

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private Integer channelId;

    getters/setters
```

When I get data from xml, any channel is retrieved.

I've achived to work with an intermediate class Channels, changing the code to:

```java
private Channels expChannels;

@XmlElement(name = "channels")
public Channels getChannels() {
    return this.expChannels;
}

public void setChannels(Channels listOfChannels) {
   this.expChannels = listOfChannels;
}
```

and defining Channels:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="channels")
public class Channels {

    private List<Channel> expChannels = new ArrayList<Channel>();

    @XmlElement(name = "channel")

    getters/setters
```

This is the structure of XML file:

```
<experiment xmlns="experiment">
    <name>Test Experiment</name>
    <file>ExperimentTemplate.xml</file>
    <channels>  <!-- List of channel's -->
        <channel>
            <id>0</id>
            <name>Channel 1</name>
            <description>Channel 1 description</description>
        </channel>
        <channel>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>Channel 2</name>
            <description>Channel 1 description</description>
        </channel>
    </channels>
</experiment>
```

Can I avoid the use of Channels class?

Comment: how the xml you are trying to read looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@XmlElementWrapper` definitely works.  For unmarshalling issues it is best to populate your object model and marshal it and compare the result to the XML you are unmarshalling.

Comment: Ok Blaise, I'll try to do it. As a mention, say that I haven't xsd file, I make myselt the model objects files.

Comment: You're right. I follow your suggestion and see the xml generated and I've finally understood some concepts that was not clear for me.

Comment: You're right. I follow your suggestion and see the xml generated and I've finally understood some concepts that was not clear for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In your case you need to add the namespace to XmlWrapper

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "channels", namespace = "experiment")
@XmlElement(name = "channel", namespace = "experiment")
private ArrayList<Channel>  expChannels;
```

I don't understand why a lone @XmlElment annotation does not need the namespace but @XmlElementWrapper does need it, but that's how it is.

It also works with a package level annotation. That way you need to specifiy the namespace only once and all @XmlElementWrapper annotations in the whole package work:

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "experiment", elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, xmlns = { @XmlNs(prefix = "", namespaceURI = "experiment") })
```

Comment: Thanks! My xml file had xmlns="http://www.example.com/my-projects-namespace" as its namespace. Adding namespace="http://www.example.com/my-projects-namespace" to XmlElementWrapper and all XmlElement annotations worked for me.